# Configure inspection for MySQL to ignore case for table names

Tags: mysql, phpstorm, case-sensitive, code-inspection

It is a cool feature in PhpStorm that strings containing SQL statements automatically get inspected.

But I have a problem with case sensitivity on table names.

Table names are case sensitive for the inspection when their identifier are enquoted in back ticks (`). For example

```
$sql = 'select * from User'
```

works fine, while

```
$sql = 'select * from `User`'
```

not. The database schema shows that this table is lowercase i. e. *user*.

Is there any option for it?

Comment: This can be caused due to the fact, that the string `User` gets interpreted as `user` while `'User'` (with backticks) really get interpreted as `User` in upper case.. So if your table is named in lower letters this is truly a right error.

Comment: I agree that the table names in the SQL statement should exactly named like in the schema, but at runtime it gets executed without any problems (on Linux `lower_case_table_names = 1` in the MySQL config doing this trick).

Comment: okay :) didn't know this setting. Anyway that was the one thing i noticed.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid there's no options for that at the moment.
It would be great if you could submit the feature request to our tracking system here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DBE#newissue=yes.

Comment: Thanks. Here is the issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-5201